# Undeterministic IRB completion behaviour?

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-1.9.3

did I found a bug in irb or am I missing something here ?

- when irb is ran without an extra initialization and completion module is loaded interactively, everything works as expected:

> ```
> irb> 'abc'.str<TAB pressed>
> irb> 'abc'.strip
> irb> 'abc Def'.str<TAB pressed>
> irb> 'abc Def'.strip
> ```

- however when ran with `irb -f -r irb/completion` or with `irb` where *.irbrc* does contain sole line `require 'irb/completion'` strange things start to happen:

> ```
> irb> 'abc'.str<TAB pressed>
> irb> 'abc'.strip
> irb> 'abc dEf'.str<TAB pressed>
> dEf'.strftime  dEf'.string    dEf'.strip     dEf'.strip!
> irb> 'abc Def'.str<TAB pressed>
> <no possible completions are displayed>
> ```

Space in a string and upper-case letter following the space somehow break completion code, but only if the completion module is loaded non-interactively !

> ```
> Ruby 1.9.3p286
> Irb 0.9.6
> Linux x86_64
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By default, irb does not have `tab completion` enabled.

The first set of irb interaction examples above are working because you have the functionality enabled in some other way. Quite likely [`wirble` gem](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/) or [`bond` gem](http://tagaholic.me/bond/) or some other similar gem is being loaded in the irb context.

Rename the ~/.irbrc file to something else so that it's not loaded in irb, and then try again. tab completion should not work.

I confirmed the tab completion behavior with `'abc Def'.str`. Seems to be a bug in the irb tab completion functionality.

Digging briefly through the [code for irb tab completion](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/completion.rb), I am yet to figure out why this is happening. :-)

Comment: The first set of irb interaction is without an initialization, ie. without loading .irbrc . As I did mentioned, the completion module was loaded interactively, so after the prompt appears I just enter `require 'irb/completion'`. The point is when loaded **this way** it works as expected, so there is a difference in behaviour for the same module !